Unit testing ASP.Net Core gRpc microservice as a whole
In unit testing an ASP.NET Core gRPC microservice, is it standard practice to run the service via Main([]) and use gRPC client classes for assertions?
If not, what are the recommended practices?
Specifically, how should configuration and mocking be handled in such tests using MSTestV2?
